# JavaScript constructor test in Google Chrome Dev console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, oop, constructor

[image]

I'm trying to create an object in javascript using the constructor function form inside Google Chrome dev console.

```
v1 = new V("Prabhas", 27);
```

When I type this, why does it return V {name:"Prabhas", age:27} - I know that's the object that's getting created - but why does it not say:

```
v1{name:"Prabhas", age:27}
```

This is also the case when I explicitly ask for object

```
v1 {The highlighted line}
```

Why does it not say:

```
v1{name:"Prabhas", age:27}
```

Any pointers would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Why would the console return the name of the variable you entered ? Useless

Answer (score 2):

It simply returns the type of the object - in your case this is `V`; `v1` is just the name of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is telling you what is the type of the object, in this case V.